# Add something to end of each .css and .jpg file

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am looking to take each `.css` file and each `.jpg` file and add this to end of all the files: `?v= + Math.floor(Math.random());` I am very new with JQuery and this is all I got so far, which is not much at all

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(something).each(function( index ) {

            //Add ?v= + Math.floor(Math.random()); to the end of each .css 
            //file and .jpg file
    });

});
```

I am looking to change this main.css to this main.css?v=

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: The actual file? Or the elements that reference files?

Comment: `Math.floor(Math.random())` always equal to `0`

Comment: I believe you are trying to prevent images and css files from being cached in browser and that is why you wish to add a random query string at end. You should do it on server side. Too late for client-side scripts to make such changes.

Comment: I think you want to diferentiate your each .css and .jpg file. Better add a counter variable ..

Comment: What is your server-side language? Unless you're running JavaScript and jquery on your server it would be best to do this on your server.

Comment: I agree with @NawedKhan. You should use expires headers of 0 seconds in .htaccess for Apache, or an alternative for whatever server type you're using. [Query strings are unreliable anyway](http://www.stevesouders.com/blog/2008/08/23/revving-filenames-dont-use-querystring/).

Comment: tymeJV - the elements that reference files

Comment: This is for caching....any examples on how I can do this on the server-side

Comment: @user3723240 Have a look at [the HTML5 Boilerplate .htaccess file](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/.htaccess#L638) for Apache. You'll want to change yours to expire after `access plus 0 seconds`.

Comment: @JoeJ so I would want to do this following: `ExpiresByType text/css                              "access plus 0 seconds"` ?

Comment: @user3723240 That's right, but you'll also need the line `ExpiresActive on` for it to work.

Comment: awesome, put in an answer and I will check it off

Answer (score 2):

For .css files:

```
$('link').each(function (i, item) {
    item.href = item.href + '?v='+ (Math.random() * 10+i);
})
```

And same thing can be applied for.jpg images.

note that every .css will have a different version number. in case you want them all to have the same number you will need to do:

```
var randomVer = (Math.random() * 10+i);

$('link').each(function (i, item) {
    item.href = item.href + '?v='+randomVer;
})
```